# Second order ODE in Julia giving wrong results

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to use the DifferentialEquations.jl provided by julia, and it's working all right until I try to use it on a second order ODE.
Consider for instance the second order ODE

x''(t) = x'(t) + 2* x(t),   with initial conditions

x'(0) = 0, x(0) = 1

which has an analytic solution given by: x(t) = 2/3 exp(-t) + 1/3 exp(2t).

To solve it numerically, I run the following code:

```
using DifferentialEquations;

function f_simple(ddu, du, u, p, t)
    ddu[1] = du[1] + 2*u[1] 
end;

du0 = [0.]
u0 = [1.]
tspan = (0.0,5.0)
prob2 = SecondOrderODEProblem(f_simple, du0, u0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob2,reltol=1e-8, abstol=1e-8);
```

With that,

```
sol(3)[2] = 122.57014434362732
```

whereas the analytic solution yields 134.50945587649028, and so I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: It works if you specify a standard integrator like `solve(prob2, alg=Tsit5())`. It might be good to open an issue in the github repo with your example though, since the specialized integrators seem to be quite imprecise here.

Comment: This problem was actually addressed by the author last year, see the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180865/2nd-order-odes-in-julia-using-differentialequations, https://github.com/SciML/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/523. Please add the version of the diffeq package.

Comment: Open an issue please.

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub. Thank you all for your help, that has helped me a bunch already!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [the documentation for DifferentialEquations.jl](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/dev/tutorials/ode_example/#Choosing-a-Solver-Algorithm), `Vern7()` is appropriate for high-accuracy solutions to non-stiff equations:

```
sol = solve(prob2, Vern7(), reltol=1e-8, abstol=1e-8)
julia> println(sol(3)[2])
134.5094558872943
```

On my machine, this matches the analytical solution quite closely. I'm not exactly sure what the default method used is: the documentation indicates that `solve` has some method of choosing an appropriate solver when one isn't specified.

For more information on `Vern7()`, check out [Jim Verner's page on Runge-Kutta algorithms](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ejverner/).

Comment: Is it a problem that `Vern7` isn't automatically chosen based on the provided `reltol`?